# AVAssetWriter, AVAssetExportSession, Video Time Difference

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation

I have a **Swift** class that takes an image and creates a 10 second video of that image.

---

I create the video using `AVAssetWriter`.
It outputs a ten seconds video. This all works as expected.

```
 func setup(){

    //Setup video size
    self.videoSize = self.getVideoSizeForImage(self.videoImage!)

    //Setup temp video path
    self.tempVideoPath = self.getTempVideoPath()

    //Setup video writer
    var videoWriter = AVAssetWriter(
        URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: self.tempVideoPath!),
        fileType: AVFileTypeMPEG4,
        error: nil)

    //Setup video writer input
    let videoSettings = [
        AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
        AVVideoWidthKey: self.videoSize!.width,
        AVVideoHeightKey: self.videoSize!.height
    ]
    let videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(
        mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
        outputSettings: videoSettings as [NSObject : AnyObject]
    )
    videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true

    //Setup video writer adaptor
    let adaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(
        assetWriterInput: videoWriterInput,
        sourcePixelBufferAttributes: [
            kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,
        ]
    )
    videoWriter.addInput(videoWriterInput)

    //Setup frame time
    self.currentFrameTime = CMTimeMake(0, 10000)

    //Start video writing session
    videoWriter.startWriting()
    videoWriter.startSessionAtSourceTime(self.currentFrameTime!)

    self.currentVideoWriter = videoWriter
    self.currentVideoWriterAdaptor = adaptor
}


  func addImageToVideoWriter(image:UIImage, duration:CGFloat){

    //Get image pixel buffer
    let buffer = self.pixelBufferFromImage(image)

    var frameTime = self.currentFrameTime!

    //Add pixel buffer to video
    let adaptor = self.currentVideoWriterAdaptor!
    while(!adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData){}
    if adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData{

        adaptor.appendPixelBuffer(
            buffer,
            withPresentationTime: frameTime
        )

        let seconds = CGFloat(CMTimeGetSeconds(frameTime))+duration
        var timescale = frameTime.timescale
        var value = CGFloat(timescale) * seconds

        frameTime.value = Int64(value)
        frameTime.timescale = Int32(timescale)

        self.currentFrameTime = frameTime
        self.lastImage = image
    }

}

   func pixelBufferFromImage(image:UIImage) -> CVPixelBufferRef{

    let size = image.size

    var pixelBuffer: Unmanaged<CVPixelBuffer>?
    let bufferOptions:CFDictionary = [
        "kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey": NSNumber(bool: true),
        "kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey": NSNumber(bool: true)
    ]
    let status:CVReturn = CVPixelBufferCreate(
        nil,
        Int(size.width),
        Int(size.height),
        OSType(kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB),
        bufferOptions,
        &pixelBuffer
    )

    let managedPixelBuffer = pixelBuffer!.takeRetainedValue()

    let lockStatus = CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer, 0)

    let pixelData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer)
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)
    let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(
        pixelData,
        Int(size.width),
        Int(size.height),
        8,
        Int(4 * size.width),
        rgbColorSpace,
        bitmapInfo
    )
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), image.CGImage)

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer, 0)

    return managedPixelBuffer
}


  func saveVideoWriterToDisk(){

    self.addImageToVideoWriter(self.lastImage!, duration: 0)

    self.currentVideoWriter?.endSessionAtSourceTime(self.currentFrameTime!)
    self.currentVideoWriterAdaptor?.assetWriterInput.markAsFinished()

    //Write video to disk
    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    self.currentVideoWriter?.finishWritingWithCompletionHandler({
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    })
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
}
```

I then use `AVAssetExportSession` and `AVMutableComposition` to add music to that video. This works most of the time.

```
func exportVideo(sourceFilePath:String, destinationFilePath:String) -> Bool{
    let fileManager = NSFileManager()
    var success = false

    //Compile audio and video together
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    /*
    //Setup audio track
    let trackAudio:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(
        AVMediaTypeAudio,
        preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID()
    )

    //Add audio file to audio track
    let audioFileAsset = AVURLAsset(URL:self.audioFileURL, options:nil)
    let audioFileAssetTrack = audioFileAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio).last as! AVAssetTrack
    trackAudio.insertTimeRange(
        audioFileAssetTrack.timeRange,
        ofTrack: audioFileAssetTrack,
        atTime: kCMTimeZero,
        error: nil
    )*/

    //Setup video track
    let trackVideo:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(
        AVMediaTypeVideo,
        preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID()
    )

    //Add video file to video track
    let videoFileAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: sourceFilePath), options: nil)
    let videoFileAssetTracks = videoFileAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if videoFileAssetTracks.count > 0{
        let videoFileAssetTrack:AVAssetTrack = videoFileAssetTracks[0] as! AVAssetTrack
        trackVideo.insertTimeRange(
            videoFileAssetTrack.timeRange,
            ofTrack: videoFileAssetTrack,
            atTime: kCMTimeZero,
            error: nil
        )
    }

    //Export compiled video to disk
    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(destinationFilePath){
        fileManager.removeItemAtPath(destinationFilePath, error: nil)
    }
    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(
        asset: composition,
        presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
    )
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    exporter.outputURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: destinationFilePath)
    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    exporter.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
        success = true
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    })
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

    //Delete file at source path
    fileManager.removeItemAtPath(sourceFilePath, error: nil)

    return success
}
```

However.

When the image is quite large (in terms of resolution, i.e. 1600*1600 and larger) the video created with AVAssetExportSession is 8 seconds instead of 10. The time difference only occurs when using large images.

---

It's not a huge problem. As it is highly unlikely people will be using this class with images that large. 
However I would still like to know what's going on and how to fix it.

Comment: Have you looked at memory consumption as your 10 second video is being created. Secondly, you don't show the loop code for adding each frame and what error checking you are doing.